# How to access elements of arrays within array (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, transpose

I'm trying to access elements from a JavaScript array:

```
[["1","John"],["2","Rajan"],["3","Hitesh"],["4","Vin"],["5","ritwik"],["6","sherry"]]
```

I want to access 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 separately in a variable and             John, Rajan, Hitesh, Vin, Ritwik, Sherry separately in a variable.
I tried converting it to a string and split(), but it doesn't work.

this is code i tried

```
var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($newarray); ?> ;    
var nJarr = jArray[0]; nJarr.toString();    
var res = nJarr.split(","); var apname = res[0];    
alert(apname);
```

but there's no alert appearing on the screen

Comment: can you share the code you have tried

Comment: what was the error found when split

Comment: this is code i tried
  var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($newarray); ?> ;  
  var nJarr = jArray[0];
  nJarr.toString();  
  var res = nJarr.split(",");
  var apname = res[0];  
  alert(apname);            
but there's no alert appearing on the screen

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ry7trxws/1/

Comment: arr[0][0] will give you value of  "1"
arr[0[1] will give you value of "john ",

arr[1][0] will give you value of  "2"
arr[1[1] will give you value of "rajan"
etc,
what you try to do exactly

Comment: For heaven's sake, do not even think about trying to manipulate data structures as strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using Underscore, then it's just

```
var transposed = _.zip.apply(0, arr);
```

and the arrays you are looking for will be in `transposed[0]` and `transposed[1]`.

You can write your own transpose function fairly easily, and it's more compact if you can use ES6 syntax:

```
transpose = arr => Object.keys(arr[0]).map(i => arr.map(e => e[i]));

>> transpose([["1","John"], ["2","Rajan"], ...]]
<< [[1, 2, ...], ["John", "Rajan", ...]]
```

If you want an ES5 version, here's one with comments:

```
function transpose(arr) {          // to transpose an array of arrays
    return Object.keys(arr[0]) .   // get the keys of first sub-array
        map(function(i) {          // and for each of these keys
            arr .                  // go through the array
                map(function(e) {  // and from each sub-array 
                    return e[i];   // grab the element with that key
                })
        ))
    ;
}
```

If you prefer old-style JS:

```
function transpose(arr) {

    // create and initialize result
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++ ) { result[i] = []; }

    // loop over subarrays
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var subarray = arr[i];

        // loop over elements of subarray and put in result
        for (var j = 0; j < subarray.length; j++) {
            result[j].push(subarray[j]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like bellow

```
var arr = [["1","John"],["2","Rajan"],["3","Hitesh"],["4","Vin"],["5","ritwik"],["6","sherry"]];
var numbers = arr.map(function(a){return a[0]}); //numbers contain 1,2,3,4,5
var names = arr.map(function(a){return a[1]}); //names contain John,Rajan...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [["1","John"],["2","Rajan"],["3","Hitesh"],["4","Vin"],["5","ritwik"],["6","sherry"]];
var IDs = [];
var names = [];
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
   IDs.push(data[i][0]);
   names.push(data[i][1]);
}

 console.log(IDs);
 console.log(names);
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamed1991/ourL9oea/1/).